# An text editor for aspx?

Tags: asp.net, html, visual-studio, code-editor

I have recently started developing in ASP.NET(C#/VB.NET) Web Forms. Apart from Notepad++ what other text editor is there for ASPX files?

I'm asking because Notepad++ gets rid of all the nice colours and formatting available for html files

EDIT

Sorry should have said I've been told apparently not to install Microsoft Visual Studio on the server.

Comment: what is less in IDE? Visual Studio is the best!

Comment: I can understand that if you are needing to edit a published page on the server then the last thing you want to be doing is loading VS.NET, especially if you are on a remote desktop!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This site might help you find the resources you need. Not sure if it's all free stuff so have a look around:  [C# Tools, a collection of development tools and utilities for C# programming](http://www.csharptools.com/#editor).

Notepad 2 is quite useful!

Answer (score 1):

Visual studio is the deFacto and arguably the best

Answer (score 1):

You can install the [Visual Studio Web Developer](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Web/) edition, it's free and may be used in commercial projects. I know this isn't your typical light-weight text editor but if you're doing web development on the production server why not do it with the proper tools?

However, you might wanna be careful with the installation, Visual Studio will by default, install a SQL Server express instance (you can't opt-out of it). You might wanna disable/uninstall this after the installation is complete, as it doesn't really belong on a web server.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out Visual Studio Express, which is a cut-down version of Visual Studio that should do exactly what you want.

http://www.microsoft.com/express/Web/

You can always upgrade to a better version later!